# Strpos is saying it didn't find the string when it should have

Tags: php, strpos

I have this:

```
$fi2 = "/var/www/server/poll/ips.txt"; //IP file
$mystring = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; //IP according to server
$findme = file_get_contents($fi2);
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);
if ($pos === true) {
    echo "Found";
} else {    
    echo "not found"; 
}
```

However, it does not say "not found" even if the IP matches something in the text file. I have done

```
echo "$mystring $findme";
```

And it outputs my IP and the text file correctly.

I have been told that I should replace

```
if ($pos === true) {
```

with

```
if ($pos !== false) {
```

Which I did and it still does not work.

Here's the code I used to save to the text file:

```
//Record IP
$fi2 = "/var/www/server/poll/ips.txt"; //IP file
file_put_contents($fi2, "\r\n$mystring", FILE_APPEND); //Stick it onto the IP file
```

Comment: Are you sure the file is loaded properly?

Comment: Yes, I used `echo` and it printed it out fine

Comment: Can you not just use preg_match(); ? Sorry I'm on iPad, can't format my comment into code where appropriate

Comment: @MarkEriksson I was told that REGEX is bad for stuff like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out myself.

I changed

```
file_put_contents($fi2, "\r\n$mystring", FILE_APPEND); //Stick it onto the IP file
```

To

```
file_put_contents($fi2, "$mystring", FILE_APPEND); //Stick it onto the IP file
```

I don't know why this fixed it (just starting PHP) but that's the reason it's broken, so if someone proposes an answer to fix it with the original line I'll accept it.

Changing `$pos === true` to `$pos !== false` also was required.

Comment: I'm really curious as to _why_ that fixed the problem. @chipperyman573 make sure you add a delimiter back in. You don't want to accidentally match the wrong IP. Without a delimiter you could match `1.2.3.41` in `1.2.3.41.2.3.5`.

Comment: thats only going to fix it if there's only one 1 in the file. Otherwise it will break again. I've updated my answer as your strpos() arguments are backwards (which is another problem)

Comment: That explains a lot. `a` matches `ab` but not the other way around. Compounded bugs are always the hardest to find.

Comment: correct. Also for future reference, use var_dump() over echo. It will highligh new lines as echo won't display them correctly in a browser.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's combination of three problems.

Firstly if the file you're loading has a new line at the end of the ip address, it's not going to match:

```
$findme = file_get_contents($fi2);
```

change to

```
$findme = trim(file_get_contents($fi2));
```

Also as others have pointed out, your pos logic is incorrect.

```
if ($pos !== false) {
```

Edit:

Also your argument order for strpos is wrong:

```
$pos = strpos($findme, $mystring);
```

Comment: try `var_dump($mystring, $findme)` and post it's output.

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the manual on [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos):

> Returns the position of where the needle exists relative to the beginning of the haystack string (independent of offset). Also note that string positions start at 0, and not 1.
>
> Returns `FALSE` if the needle was not found.

So the result is a numeric position or `FALSE`, this means that `$pos === true` **always** fails! Another problem is the signature of `strpos()` is the following:

> `mixed strpos ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] )`

You mixed up `$haystack` and `$needle` which may be caused by the poor naming. Try something like this:

```
$fi2 = "/var/www/server/poll/ips.txt"; //IP file
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; //IP according to server
$file = file_get_contents($fi2);
$pos = strpos($file, $ip);// ($findme, $mystring)
if ($pos !== FALSE) {
    echo "found";
} else {
    echo "not found";
}
```

Comment: @chipperyman573 Please see the update. The arguments for `strpos()` were in wrong order

Answer (score 0):

[`strpos`](http://php.net/strpos) returns a number or `false` if not found.

The correct if statement would be:

```
if ($pos !== false) {
```

Another common mistake is to write:

```
if (!$pos) {
```

But if `$pos` is `0` - which happens if the string is found at the beginning of the string - this check will also fail.

Comment: Are you super duper sure the IP is in the file? Try it with `$findme = $mystring`, that should match.

Comment: I am ultra super duper sure, I just downloaded to my computer and manually checked.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative for the if statement:

```
if(!is_bool($pos)){
```